# How to Pass Pipeline Variables from Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run few nunit tests in Azure pipeline. I am passing few test parameters using test run settings in the nunit script and also defined those variables in Pipleline as well. After a test, I have to change the variable in Azure pipeline based on the test output, which can be used in subsequent scripts. I tried to multiple ways but nothing seems to work out. I did try to set the pipeline variables in Using powershell commands in piepline it self, but its not working when i tried to do the same from TestAssemblies (C# code).

YAML code

```
pool:
  name: New Agent Pool
  demands: vstest

variables:
  sauce: 'tomato'
  sauce1: 'something'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
  enabled: false

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  enabled: false

- powershell: |
   # Write your PowerShell commands here.

   Write-Output sauce = $(sauce)
   Write-Output sauce1 = $(sauce1)

  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'Name=UnitTest1'
    runSettingsFile: SeleniumTest.ABC/Test.runsettings
    overrideTestrunParameters: '-sauce $(sauce)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- powershell: |
   # Write your PowerShell commands here.

   Write-Output sauce = $(sauce)
   Write-Output sauce1 = $(sauce1)

  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

```
    [Test]
    //[Category ("Google")]
    public void UnitTest1()
    {
        string sauce = TestContext.Parameters["sauce"];
        string sauce1 = TestContext.Parameters["sauce1"];
        TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(sauce);
        TestContext.Progress.WriteLine(sauce1);
        string text = "Write-Output '##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce;isOutput=true]crushed tomatoes'";
        string op = RunScript(text);
        TestContext.WriteLine(op);
    }


    private string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        // create Powershell runspace
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        // close the runspace
        runspace.Close();

        // convert the script result into a single string
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague to me. Are you trying to set task input parameters in a PowerShell script, or trying to read a parameter in your test code?

Comment: I was trying to override Azure pipeline variable through a Test script, so that I can use that in subsequent Azure tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a complex way to print message through the powershell execution. You can use `TestContext.Progress.WriteLine`:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes test project");
        Assert.Pass();
    }
```

Here is my result:

[image]

Additionally check path to your tests. If your use net core, that can be like:

```
- task: VSTest@2

  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'

  inputs:

    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\netcoreapp3.1\YourTestLib.dll
     !**\obj\**

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Aleksander. It worked for me. I missed out a very simple way :D